# How to read & write a list to/from a file with vimscript

Tags: vim

I've got some configuration data that's stored in a list - I'd like to read and write it from an external file. Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: Note: There is a [dedicated site for vi & vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```viml
let data = readfile('config')
...
if writefile(data, 'config')
    echomsg 'write error'
endif
```